# Asp.Net 5 ,dnx : Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, dnx

I am working on Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and getting the below error when i try to run an Asp.net 5 application.

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Description:** An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Source Error:**

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' could not be loaded.

**=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = dnx.clr.managed
 (Partial)**
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: dnx.clr.managed | Domain ID: 6
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/Selva/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta8/bin
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL

## Calling assembly : (Unknown).

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Found application configuration file (C:\Projects\The World\The World\src\The World\wwwroot\Web.config).
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Projects\The World\The World\src\The World\wwwroot\Web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Users\Selva\Documents\IISExpress\config\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Selva/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta8/bin/dnx.clr.managed.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Selva/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta8/bin/dnx.clr.managed/dnx.clr.managed.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Selva/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta8/bin/dnx.clr.managed.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/Selva/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-clr-win-x64.1.0.0-beta8/bin/dnx.clr.managed/dnx.clr.managed.EXE.

**Stack Trace:**

[FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'dnx.clr.managed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.]

[TypeLoadException: The domain manager specified by the host could not be instantiated.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +556

[HttpException (0x80004005): The domain manager specified by the host could not be instantiated.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +579
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +118
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +726

Answer (score 0):

`dnx.clr.managed` was renamed to `Microsoft.Dnx.Host.Clr` in beta-7. Clean your solution, update tooling, make sure you have correct references and rebuild/republish your project.

Comment: How to update the tooling? how to make sure you have correct references and rebuild/republish your project? Kindly help me with more details. Sorry to bother you. i am newbie to .net

Comment: I am using dnx beta8.

Comment: You can get the latest tooling from here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49442. Here are the instructions http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-windows.html. In general http://docs.asp.net/ is a good starting point (even though some topic are still pending)